# Is there a way to get the carrier information for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uidevice

I know this question was asked back in 2008 (with the answer being no), but with the new Verizon iPhones is there anything in place in the API that would allow this information to be reached?

I see there is nothing in `UIDevice` (where you generally get the other related information) specifically pertaining to this, but perhaps the "`model`" property in `UIDevice` has a Verizon specific name? Has anyone run across anyway to find this out? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString *mcc = [carrier mobileCountryCode];
NSString *mnc = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
```

[Mobile Network Codes (MNC) USA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_network_codes_in_the_United_States)

iOS4

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This link works for me: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html